# EditText does not take the value if entered a float value

Tags: java, android

Here's my code

```
if(numberbyUser.getText().toString().equals(""))
{
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter a Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    message = "Please Enter a Number !!";
    DialogFunction();
}
```

If I enter a value for eg: 1.5 code goes into the above loop. But for values which are not decimal code just works fine.

Can somebody please tell me whats going wrong?

Comment: Post the code where you initialize numberbyUser

Comment: in the xml of your edit text have youed some thing like `android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"` where `numberDecimal` is for Decimal nubers and `numberSigned`Signed integers.

Comment: numberbyuser will be my edit text box
numberbyUser = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.numberbyUser);
 <EditText
         android:id="@+id/numberbyUser"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:inputType="numberDecimal"
         android:ems="10" />

Comment: to put inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that make the `EditText` field as a text `android:inputType="text"` then do the conversion. Try this:

```
    String sNumberByUser = numberbyUser.getText().toString();
    Double number = 0.0;

    try{
        if(!sNumberByUser.equals("")){
            // This will accept decimal and non-decimal number
            number = Double.parseDouble(sNumberByUser);

            //do your process here

        }else{
            throw new NumberFormatException();
        }

    //Catch if not a number.
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
        message = "Please Enter a Number !!";
        DialogFunction();
    }
```

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Editable to String

Comment: I did add numberbyUser.getText().toString(); , which solves the error

Comment: indeed, sorry i forgot to include the .toString();

Comment: im glad i was able to help you :)) it would be great if you will accept it as an answer :) TIA

Comment: I am sorry but i tried , this is not working. This is not getting executed.

Comment: why ? what happen please elaborate more

Comment: Sorry your solution just worked fine. I did some mistake in execution. Thanks for your support

Comment: My question got -1 , is it such a bad question to ask :) ??

Comment: @user3374737 -1 are now gone. XD :)

Comment: @user3374737 there's alot of people here downvoting an answer or question without providing an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

can you post the XML for the your edittext...it may be possible that you set the 
inputType="number" instead of "decimal..."

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/phone"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="decimal" />
```

change inputType attribute to "decimal"

Comment: <EditText
         android:id="@+id/numberbyUser"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:inputType="numberDecimal"
         android:ems="10" />

Comment: I am using inputtype as "numberDecimal" which enables me to enter the values. But the values somehow are getting compared to ""

Comment: Code works fine if i just add a print in the "if" code. Is there any possible explanation to this ???

Comment: try to log the value of numberbyUser and check whether the value correctly coming or not and secondly try to store the value of the value of edittext separately in other string variable and then compare it with the str.equals("") and put the if condition in a try..catch block

Answer (score 0):

```
if(numberbyUser.getText().length() > 0) {
     String numberString = numberByUser.getText().toString();
     Double number = Double.parseDouble(numberString);
     //To operation with entered number.
} else {
     message = "Please enter number.";
     DialogFunction();
}
```

And in your layout add **android:inputType = "numberDecimal"**

Hope this will help you.